# I just proved that $ℂ$ is not a field. What is the mistake in my reasoning?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

What is the mistake in my reasoning?

Consider $(X^2+1)$ in $ℝ[X]$. Then $(X^2+1)⊂(X^2,1)$. Because if $f \in (X^2+1)$. Then $f=(X^2+1)g=X^2g+1⋅g$. So $f \in (X^2,1)$. Therefore $(X^2+1)$ not a maximal ideal. And therefore $ℝ[x]/(X^2+1)≅ℂ$ is not a field.

Comment: Well, $(X^2,1) = (1) = \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: Oh of course, haha, thanks !

Comment: Deletion or answer?

Comment: Oh, ehm.. If anyone wants to delete it, im fine. If anyone wants to answer it, that's fine to me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mistake is that you didn't notice that the ideal $(X^2,1)$ contains $1$, and therefore is the entire ring $\mathbb{R}[X]$. Of course, the unit ideal is an ideal that properly contains all maximal ideals.